# ERROR Could not load type 'dotless.Core.configuration.WebConfigConfigurationLoader' from assembly 'dotless.Core, Version=1.5.3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotless, system.web.optimization

I am working with asp.net MVC application(.net framework 4.6.1), I want to use the bundle for `.less` files so I register the bundles in `BundleConfig` file as follows

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
   //other bundles are here ..
    bundles.Add(new LessBundle("~/Content/less").Include("~/Content/*.less"));
}
```

in order to use the `less` I already installed the following packages from package manager

```
dotless.Core.1.6.0.1
dotless.AspNetHandler.1.6.0.1
System.Web.Optimization.Less.1.3.4
```

this is my "_Layout.cshtml"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style=" height: 100%;
  margin: 0;">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/less")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body style="padding:0;margin:0;" class="col-12 h-100">
    <div class="h-100 border">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

now when I am running the application, getting following error at     `@Styles.Render("~/Content/less")`

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'dotless.Core.configuration.WebConfigConfigurationLoader' from assembly 'dotless.Core, Version=1.5.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96b446c9e63eae34'.'

[image]

I googled for this error and got [dotless: Don’t upgrade your dotless if you use System.Web.Optimization.Less](https://sobari.tanuwijaya.net/index.php/2018/04/21/dotless-dont-upgrade-your-dotless-if-you-use-system-web-optimization-less) link who already encountered with this issue, but I still getting same error even followed the their suggestion.

Please help if some one already faced this issue.

Comment: From the error message, without no knowledge of dotless, looks like it has been already answered, check for `Could not load type` answers in stack overflow before posting a question about it.

Comment: @bradbury9 , This is not the issue related the loading the type this is something related to version issue of dotless configuration please check this link https://sobari.tanuwijaya.net/index.php/2018/04/21/dotless-dont-upgrade-your-dotless-if-you-use-system-web-optimization-less/

Comment: The error message point that cannot load the WebConfigConfigurationLoader that is in the dotless.Core assembly. Have you checked if the dotless.Core.dll is added as a reference to your project?

Comment: @bradbury9 I have attached the dotless assembly screenshot of my application can you look .. I have references of all dlls.

Answer (score 3):

Seems `System.Web.Optimization.Less` still expects `WebConfigConfigurationLoader` to be in the `dotless.Core` assembly, which it isn't as of **dotless 1.6** (it's been moved to the new `dotless.AspNet` assembly).

I reverted to **dotless 1.5.2** and everything works fine now.